# Javascript validating multiple fields

Tags: javascript, html

I want to validate multiple fields in my form. For that i don't want to write separate condition for all the fields. So i have assigned the error messages like a key and value pair.
If i leave all the fields without typing any value then it should populate error message.

This is my html code.

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/validate_register.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="valid">
        <tr>
            <td>id:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="id1" placeHolder="Enter your name"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="id2" placeHolder="Enter your email"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>password:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="id3" placeHolder="Enter your password"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>address:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="id4" placeHolder="Enter your address"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>contact no:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="id5" placeHolder="Enter your contact no"/></td>
        </tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" onclick="validate()" value="submit"> </td></tr></table>  
  </body>
```

This is my javascript code.

```
function validate () {
        var error={
                    id1:'name Cannot be empty',
                    id2:'email cannot be empty',
                    id3:'password cannot be empty',
                    id4:'address Cannot be empty',
                    id5:'contactno cannot be empty'

        }
        var elements=document.querySelectorAll('input');
        for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){

        if(elements[i]['value']=="")
        {
                    var id=elements[i]['id'];
                    document.querySelector("."+id).innerHTML=error[id];
        }
        }

 }
```

This shows an error on the `document.querySelector("."+id).innerHTML=error[id];` line about something being `null`.

Comment: document.querySelector("."+id).innerHTML=error[id];   it shows error in this line. innerHTML is null

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> document.querySelector("."+id).innerHTML=error[id];

That expects you to have an element with a class corresponding to the `input`'s `id` (e.g., 
`class="id2"` and such). You haven't shown any of those in your question. `querySelector` returns `null` if it can't find a matching element.

If you add a series of things like this in appropriate locations:

```
<span class="id1"></span>
```

...then that element will get the error message for your `<input id="id1">`. Or of course, as these elements are unique, you could use `id`s like `error_id1`, `error_id2`, and such.

Here's a complete example using classes: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/puwifuvu/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="valid">
      <tr>
        <td>id:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="id1" placeHolder="Enter your name"/><span class="id1"></span></td></tr>
      <tr><td>email:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="id2" placeHolder="Enter your email"/><span class="id2"></span></td></tr>
      <tr><td>password:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="id3" placeHolder="Enter your password"/><span class="id3"></span></td></tr>
      <tr><td>address:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="id4" placeHolder="Enter your address"/><span class="id4"></span></td></tr>
      <tr><td>contact no:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="id5" placeHolder="Enter your contact no"/><span class="id5"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td><input type="button" onclick="validate()" value="submit"> </td></tr></table>  
  </body>
  <script>
    "use strict";

    function validate () {
      var error={
        id1:'name Cannot be empty',
        id2:'email cannot be empty',
        id3:'password cannot be empty',
        id4:'address Cannot be empty',
        id5:'contactno cannot be empty'

      }
      var elements=document.querySelectorAll('input');
      for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){

        var id=elements[i]['id'];
        document.querySelector("."+id).innerHTML=elements[i].value ? "" : error[id];
      }

    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above, I've also *cleared* the errors when the field had a value, so that the second time it runs, the error disappears. (I also changed the submit button to just a button, but that's only so the form doesn't get submitted nowhere in the example.)

---

Side note: I'd move `validate` to an `onsubmit` on the form, and have it return `false` if there are any errors.

Comment: Thank you. Its working fine. Is there any other way to minimize my code? Instead of giving 5 span classes for 5 fields, how can i give a common class and i also need to access it in my script.

Comment: @user3764346: You have lots of options. For instance, rather than having the `spans` in the markup, you could add them (using either `insertAdjacentHTML` or `createElement` combined with `insertBefore`) if there's an error and remove them (if present) if there isn't. My suggestion really only makes sense if the error for each field can vary (for instance, if you check the `email` field has a `@` in it as well as checking it's not blank); if it can't, you could put the spans *containing* the errors in the markup initially hidden, and then show/hide them in validate`. Lots of choices.

Answer (score -1):

`.` is for classes. If you want to detect ids, you need to use `#`. Moreover, you need to use `value`, not `innerHTML`. So, correct

```
document.querySelector("."+id).innerHTML=error[id];
```

to

```
document.querySelector("#"+id).value=error[id];
```